# Why is a simple iterator not readable?

Tags: c++, range-v3

This code does not compile with `range-v3` `0.10.0` (or with `master`). It does compile with `range-v3` `0.9.1`.

```
#include "range/v3/all.hpp"

struct double_it {
  using value_type = double;
  double x;
  double& operator*() { return x; }
  const double& operator*() const { return x; }
};
static_assert(ranges::readable<double_it>);
```

Which version is right ? In `master`, a type `I` is `readable` only if `same_as<iter_reference_t<I const>, iter_reference_t<I>>`. I don't understand why the return type of `operator*` should be the same as the one of `operator* const`.

Note: issue submitted on github [here](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/1461).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [P1878](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1878r0.pdf), which has all the rationale for this late design change. Iterators represent indirections. In C++, `const`-ness is shallow, meaning it doesn't follow indirections. Whether you dereference an `int*` or an `int*const`, the result you get back is the same: `int&`. The top-level `const` doesn't -- and shouldn't -- matter. Iterators do as the pointers do. They must, because a pointer is a valid model of the iterator concept.

To make this distinction more explicit, in C++20, the `readable` concept is called `indirectly_readable`.

TL;DR: Don't make the reference type of your iterator depend on the `const`-ness of the iterator itself.

Comment: Which means `double& operator*() const { return x; }`? It makes sense actually. Thanks!

Comment: What is the process in which the Ranges TS working draft (N4560) is updated? I usually refer to that document when working with ranges, but I realize (from my answer and yours) that I should not rely solely on it. Or, in other terms, where should I turn if I want to (try to) stay up to date with range-v3 in terms of the underlying draft standardese?

Comment: The C++20 draft standard. The Ranges TS is years it of date now and will not be updated.

Comment: But `double& operator*() const {return x;}` is wrong for a different reason. The reference returned by an iterator's `operator*` should be valid even after the lifetime of the iterator ends. The implication is that iterators should never return a reference to something stored in the iterator itself. These are so-called "stashing" iterators, and they cause STL algorithms all sorts of trouble. In this case, I would just return the `double` by value. If it's a large object, store it in the range and have the iterator return a reference to _that_. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be at the very least an inconsistency in `range-v3` as compared to the Ranges TS working draft.

There's a quite sparse description as for why [these `same_as` predicates were added to](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/aa8a1d882782d352898bc21142607c2c48558748/include/range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp#L135) to the `readable` concept for iterators in [`range-v3` issue 1449](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/1449).

> #### Get the range library compiling with msvc 19.24.28319 with /std:c++17
>
> ...
>
> ```
> - CPP_concept_fragment(readable_, (I),
> + CPP_concept_fragment(readable_,
> +     requires (/*I const i*/) //
> +     (
> +         // { *i } -> same_as<iter_reference_t<I>>;
> +         // { iter_move(i) } -> same_as<iter_rvalue_reference_t<I>>;
> +         0
> +     ) &&
> +     same_as<iter_reference_t<I const>, iter_reference_t<I>> &&
> +     same_as<iter_rvalue_reference_t<I const>, iter_rvalue_reference_t<I>> &&
>       common_reference_with<iter_reference_t<I> &&, iter_value_t<I> &> &&
>       common_reference_with<iter_reference_t<I> &&,
>                             iter_rvalue_reference_t<I> &&> &&
>       common_reference_with<iter_rvalue_reference_t<I> &&, iter_value_t<I> const &>
>   );
> ```

It seems the `same_as` predicates in the concept's implementation are intended to implement the requirement of:

> ```
> // { *i } -> same_as<iter_reference_t<I>>;
> // { iter_move(i) } -> same_as<iter_rvalue_reference_t<I>>;
> ```

Which were present (as comments in `range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp`) even prior to this implementation change.

However, afaics, none of these requirements are present in the [working draft of [iterators.readable]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ranges-ts/iterators.readable) of Ranges TS (nor in [the current `HEAD` of ericniebler/stl2](https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/blob/3b4b81a961b17528d38589c1dfb0c41b4228c6a8/iterators.tex#L976) from which the previous linked draft is generated).

> #### [iterators.readable] Concept Readable
>
> The Readable concept is satisfied by types that are readable by
>   applying operator* including pointers, smart pointers, and iterators.
>
> ```
> template <class In>
> concept bool Readable =
>   requires {
>     typename value_type_t<In>;
>     typename reference_t<In>;
>     typename rvalue_reference_t<In>;
>   } &&
>   CommonReference<reference_t<In>&&, value_type_t<In>&> &&
>   CommonReference<reference_t<In>&&, rvalue_reference_t<In>&&> &&
>   CommonReference<rvalue_reference_t<In>&&, const value_type_t<In>&>;
> ```

It may be a good idea to [report this as an issue](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues) to, at the very least, sort out why the `range-v3` implementation seemingly differs from `[iterators.readable]` of Ranges TS.

Comment: Thanks. I will report the issue.