How to implement a stashing movable input iterator?
I have an input iterator that can walk through a file and parse records from it along the way. Each parsed record is stored in the iterator and owned by it ("stashed").
The records are not lightweight and there are a lot of them, so it would be unfortunate to copy the values. I'd like to be able to move them out of the iterator, so I define dereferencing like so:
Record& operator*() { return this->record; }

This code works:
Record r = std::move(*it); // no copy

Then I wanted to achieve compile-time safety for this iterator using appropriate C++20 concepts, and I've added:
static_assert(std::input_iterator<Iterator>);

It fails, because a part of std::input_iterator - std::indirectly_readable - requires that const Iterator is dereferenceable (related question: Why is a simple iterator not readable?). I can't make my operator* work on const, because then it has to return a const reference and move will actually copy:
const Record& operator*() const { return this->record; }

Record r = std::move(*it); // copy, 'cause can't move const objects

I've found that using static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator) works with a mutable dereference. It could be ok for static checks, but I find it confusing, because my iterator is not an output_iterator conceptually.
Another related problem is that std::move_iterator doesn't work with this mutable dereference operator, because its operator*() is const, defined as:
reference operator*() const { return ranges::iter_move(__current_); }

where __current_ will be bound to my Iterator instance, and it will have type const Iterator in this context, which iter_move wants to dereference and fails, because it doesn't support immutable dereference (and even if it did by adding const, it wouldn't work properly, it would deceptively copy the value instead of moving).
What would be an alternative design to achieve moveability of a stashing iterator, and make move_iterator work?

Make the Record member mutable?

Can you have two overloads of operator*, one const and one non-const?

@KerrekSB unfortunately it doesn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996431/why-is-a-simple-iterator-not-readable

Iterators are meant to be cheap to move or copy. You shouldn't hold the Record in the iterator. What many ranges / range adaptors do instead is to hold it in the range, and simply hold a pointer in the iterator:
struct record_range {
private:
    Record cache;
public:
    struct iterator {
    private:
        friend record_range;
        record_range* parent;
        explicit iterator(record_range* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = Record;
        Record& operator*() const { return parent->cache; }
        iterator& operator++() { advance_record(parent->cache); return *this; }
        void operator++(int) { ++*this; }
    };
    friend bool operator==(iterator it, std::default_sentinel_t) {
        return is_past_the_end_record(it.parent->cache);
    }
    iterator begin() { read_first_record(cache); return iterator{ this }; }
    std::default_sentinel_t end() const { return {}; }
};

static_assert(std::input_iterator<record_range::iterator>);
static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<record_range>);


Thanks. I was considering ranges/views. It is probably a good solution for C++23, but I'd like to solve it in the context of C++20 where support of custom ranges/views is still lagging in some compilers.

@battlmonstr the only thing this implementation uses from the ranges proposal is std::default_sentinel_t, which is an empty type. You can substitute your own if you want C++17 support

@Caleth I'm not sure how compatible is it with range algorithms, and even if I improve it to be compatible, ranges on C++20 clang are handicapped. This solution is fine if we assume range-v3 lib dependency, but with bare STL, I'd have to create an extra range variable for each iteration, which is a compromise. Why create an extra object for each iteration if there's already one? (the iterator itself)

@Artyer You are suggesting to not use a stashing iterator. Could you clarify why is it a bad idea besides the move problem? Could you please clarify your point "iterators are meant to be cheap to move or copy"? Do you know any links that confirm/expand on this opinion? I've heard that some STL iterators use that stashing design, but I'm not sure if they regret and why.

@battlmonstr this is a type that's compatible with, not dependant on, <ranges>, apart from using std::default_sentinel_t, which is totally replaceable. record_range::iterator is a C++17 input iterator

@battlmonstr "iterators are meant to be cheap to move or copy" is evidenced by all the <algorithm>s that take them by value

@battlmonstr For "similar stashing designs", ctrl+f for non-propagating-cache in [range.adaptors] This design is pretty similar to the proposed std::views::cache_last. Most range algorithms take iterators by value, which is why you want your copy or move to be cheap.

@Caleth you can std::move(it) into an algorithm to avoid a copy.

@Artyer I mean pre-ranges-era STL iterators. By "stashing" I mean owning, not referencing a "parent". Thanks for the link ayway.

I think you are talking about std::istream_iterator, which eagerly reads from the stream

@battlmonstr See here for some problems with it

@Caleth, this article is from 2013 when move was not a widespread thing, but I get your point. If you can find more evidence that input iterators are expected to be copied willy-nilly by some algos/libs, and make an answer, I'll accept it as correct.
The record_range solution is strange without ranges support, and it abandons the idea of "stashing" without a definitive reason. Nevertheless this solution becomes viable once we migrate to C++23 (when compilers/OSes support it).

"The record_range solution is strange without ranges support" not really. std::vector is a range, and has been all along. It's similar to that.

Also the article is from the author of the ranges proposal, and move doesn't help any of the issues that it raises
